# How to run matlab from the command line and print to the command line?

Tags: matlab, command-line-interface

I want to run a script on windows dos terminal where the script will display "Hello world" to the terminal I executed this from e.g.

> matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -wait -r printToCommandLine.m

Where printToCommandLine.m contains:

> system(sprintf('echo Hello world'));

but it only prints to the matlab command window that gets generated when executing the script

Comment: I don't think this behavior is supported on Windows. See [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/).

Comment: Hmm.. is there any way to notify the command line of anything? I basically have a very long Matlab script and I want to display when a certain process is finished e.g. "Process A is complete..."

Comment: Alternative 1: install Linux. Alternative 2: use Octave. Sorry I don't have any better news for you.

Comment: @kkawabat Wrap the call to Matlab in its own executable that prints a string when it's finished?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I want to print a string in the middle of the Matlab file since it's one script but has multiple parts within the script. I can separate the processes into different scripts and wrap those in but that would be difficult for my case.

Comment: This has been answered in Matlab Central:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102082-how-do-i-call-matlab-from-the-dos-prompt

Comment: @KardiTeknomo The Q&A you link do not cover this question, specifically the "print to the command line" part

Comment: I dont know if this helps but if you compile your code as an `exe`, then when you run it from a dos prompt the output will be written to a dos the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, I am not shure, if the syntax has changed, but I have to call the script without the file extension '.m':

```
matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -wait -r printToCommandLine
```

Otherwise I will get an error within MATLAB.

**Second**, this is just a work around, but you can print your current command line output to a log file e.g. 'log.txt' using

```
matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -wait -logfile "log.txt" -r printToCommandLine
```

The log file will be updated at runtime. To test this, I created a small example script and had a look how 'log.txt' changes during execution:

```
disp('Script execution started. Waiting 10 seconds...')
pause(10)
disp('...waited 10 seconds.');
```

This is not exactly what you wanted but it gives you the chance to get actual information about the current command line output during your execution (in a text file).

We use this for automated (remote) testing to print our MATLAB command line output to the console **after** the tests pass with

```
type log.txt
```